# Descendant non-generic class into Base generic class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Usually I Use interfaces or base classes as paramter types when passing derived objects to a method.
For example

```
Method1(ICar car);
Method2(BaseClass derivedClass);
```

But what about a Generic base class when the descendant class isn't generic ?

```
public class GenericBaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass
{}

public class GenericDerivedClass1 : GenericBaseClass<DerivedClass1>
{}
```

I can write something like

```
Method3(GenericBaseClass<BaseClass> class);
```

but I can't pass to this method am object of type `GenericDerivedClass1`.

Is there any way how to pass my descendant class to this method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make your Method3 generic:

```
private void Method3<T>(GenericBaseClass<T> baseClass)
{

}
```

and then you can call it like this:

```
Method3(new GenericDerivedClass1());
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use non-generic base class for your generics:

```
abstract class GenericBaseClass
{
}

public class GenericDerivedClass1<T> : GenericBaseClass where T : DerivedClass1
{
}
```

Another solution is to use intefaces as pointed out in [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205113358/http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2005/12/05/62273.aspx) article.